# Sending a C# string to aspx.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a C# string that contains the answer to the question "May we contact?"  How do I transfer that to our aspx webpage?  The c# string is in the code behind page.

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer that to our aspx webpage"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is a `protected` (at least) property on the page then it can be accessed in the page's markup.  So the string would be something like this at the class level:

```
protected string MyString { get; set; }
```

And in the page markup you can access its value:

```
<%= MyString %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the string to another page besides the code-behind it lives in, then use a query string entry to pass it to the URL you are redirecting to. If you want the current page to access the C# string, then make the string a `protected` property so the page can use it an embedded code block.